# htaccess reading files from folder with conditional

Tags: apache, .htaccess

structure in root is:

```
  ROOT\_public
  ROOT\_blog
  ROOT\_about
```

when something comes to domain.com/blog it will read root_blog (first)
when something comes to domain.com/maps it will read root_maps (second)
when comes everything else, it will read root_public folder .. (third)

third is doesnt work!

why?

```
RewriteEngine on 

# rewrite to trailing shash in domain/about and domain/maps 
RewriteRule ^(about|blog|docs)$ /$1/ [R]

# rewrite domain.com/about/something to /_about/something 
RewriteRule ^(about|blog|docs)/(.*)$ /_$1/$2/ 

# rewrite anything that doesn't start about/ or maps/ to _public 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(about|maps|docs)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _public/$1
```

i havent idea, why its doesnt work. please help. thank you!

Comment: a keď príde domena.com/blog načíta _blog, rovnako ako aj about (a pridá lomítko nakoniec) čo mi však nefunguje je tretí, posledný krok a to je VŠETKO ČO NIE JE ABOUT ALEBO BLOG presmeruj do _PUBLIC no offense, but I really don't understand this...

Comment: :D sorry, but it was in my language (i think and write at the same time) .. its not nessesery :D thank you (funny commnent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/somethingelse will be directed to _public/somethingelse
_public/somethingelse will in turn be directed to _public/_public/somethingelse
_public/_public/somethingelse ...etc.

You need to stop rewriting if already rewritten.

```
RewriteRule ^_ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(about|maps|docs)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _public/$1
```

The added line will match anything starting with "_" and stop applying any rules below it.